# To Dispose() or Not To Dispose() elements in an array of IDisposable objects?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, idisposable

There are lots of examples of Arrays or Lists of IDisposable objects being returned from functions in .NET. For example, `Process.GetProcesses()`.

- If I call that method is it my responsibility to Dispose() of all the members of the array as I iterate through them?
- Why should it be my responsibility since I never created the objects and the array that I was given is just pointers to the objects which were created outside of my code.

**I always thought it was the creator's burden to Dispose().
So what is the proper rule here?**

Comment: There is no way for the `Creator` to dispose of them or parts inside there classes as there is no destructor. They have no control of you setting a variable to nothing to then disposing there object or contents that require disposing.

Comment: Sure, you can, for Process.GetProcesses() you can keep an internal array of all the Process() objects you ever returned to callers and then periodically check if you are the only one that has a reference to the object and if so Dispose()

Comment: @Denis Determining if anyone else has a reference to it isn't something that you can actually do.

Comment: Determining if anyone else has a reference isn't something you need to do. The Process object tracks metadata about a process, not the process itself.  You can Dispose a Process when you are done querying its metadata; it will not cause the process to exit. You can call Process.GetProcesses twice, Dispose everything from the first call, and the Processes from the second call will still work as expected without throwing an ObjectDisposedException.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no general rule.  It's going to depend on the situation, and how the method in question is designed, as to whether or not "you" are responsible for disposing of objects you have access to.  This is where documentation is often important to help users of the type understand their responsibilities.

> I always thought it was the creator's burden to `Dispose()`

This cannot be strictly true.  It is sometimes the case that a disposable object will out-live the lifetime of the block of code creating it.  While it *simplest* when the creator *can* dispose of the object, sometimes it's simply impossible for them to be able to.  When returning a disposable object from a method is one situation where it's often not be possible for the code creating the disposable object to clean it up, as it's lifetime needs to be *smaller* than the lifetime of the disposable object.

Comment: I can create a disposable object by instantiating one within the declaration of a using block. Would a using block not be exactly what solves this? The lifetime of the method call creating the disposable object is smaller than the actual disposable object itself...?
If this is not the case and I'm missing the point, might I convince you to add an example (even a contrived one) to your answer?

Comment: Gosh, I don't read documentation that carefully for every class that I use. You sure there isn't some rule?

Comment: @Denis, no there is no one rule for this situation. You should decide it by yourself.

Comment: @WimOmbelets When creating a disposable object from a method who's lifetime is larger than the lifetime of the disposable object, you can use a `using`, and it's all just fine.  When the disposable object needs to outlife the method that declares it (as tends to happen when you're returning it from the method) a `using` doesn't help).

Comment: @Denis If the type is disposable, and you don't know if you should dispose of it or not, then you'd need to check the documentation.  Since it's fairly uncommon to have methods returning disposable objects in the first place, it doesn't actually come up all that often.

Comment: @Servy I'd say it is not that uncommon for methods to return a disposable (streams, sessions, ...), but a collection of disposables as in OPs `GetProcesses` example is certainly exceptional. The only "general" rule as to who is responsible for disposal then is determined by who is considered the owner of the resource, which in most cases would be the client requesting the resource.

Answer (score 2):

With relatively few exceptions (most of which could be described as least-of-evils approaches to dealing with poorly-designed code that can't be changed), every `IDisposable` instance should at any given moment in time have exactly one well-defined owner.  In cases where a method returns something of a type that implements `IDisposable`, the contract for the method will specify whether the method is relinquishing ownership (in which case the caller should ensure that the object gets disposed--either by disposing of the object itself or relinquishing ownership to someone else), or whether the method is merely returning a reference to an object *which is owned by someone else*.

In properly-written code, the question of whether or not an object should be disposed *is rarely a judgment call*.  The owner of an object should ensure that it gets disposed; nobody else should dispose it.  Occasionally it may be necessary to have a method accept a parameter indicating whether the method should transfer ownership of an `IDisposable`.  For example, if code wants to create a sound, pass it to a "start playing sound" method, and never wants to deal with that sound again, it may be most convenient to have the code to play the sound accept take and dispose the sound when it's done; if code wants to be able to play a sound repeatedly, however, and will ensure that the sound object will stay alive as long as it's needed, it would be more convenient for the sound-playing code to *not* take ownership.  Using separate methods may in some ways be cleaner, but using a parameter can aid encapsulation.

Generally, when code returns a list of objects that implement `IDisposable`, the purpose of the code is to *identify* objects without conveying any ownership interest in them.  In the absence of an ownership interest, code receiving such a list should *not* call `Dispose` on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetProcesses` method does not allocate any handles (or other non managed resources) within the `Process` instances returned.

Only if you call certain methods on the returned `Process` instances are handles created, in almost all cases these are released before returning (e.g. `Process.Kill`).

Therefore it is completely unnecessary in most situations to dispose every `Process` instance returned.

Comment: Could you expand upon your argument? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) is fairly adamant that you should.

Answer (score -1):

The rule is very simple: if you think that other programs will use your `IDisposables`, then do not destroy them. Otherwise, do it.

For example: `GetProcesses()` returns other processes being potentialy used by other programs, so **you shouldn't dispose** them.

From other side, files you've opened should be released for other processes in OS, so you should close and dispose wrapper streams above them (say, **you should dispose** steam returned by `File.Open` method).

**Update**:
[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx):

> - **DO** implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing
>     instances of disposable types. See the Basic Dispose Pattern section
>     for details on the basic pattern.   If a type is responsible for the
>     lifetime of other disposable objects, developers need a way to dispose
>     of them, too. Using the container’s Dispose method is a convenient way
>     to make this possible.
>
>   - **DO** implement the Basic Dispose Pattern
>       and provide a finalizer on types holding resources that need to be
>       freed explicitly and that do not have finalizers.
>       For example, the pattern should be implemented on types storing unmanaged memory buffers. The Finalizable Types section discusses guidelines related to
>       implementing finalizers.
>   - **CONSIDER** implementing the Basic Dispose Pattern on classes that themselves don’t hold unmanaged resources or disposable objects but are likely to have subtypes that do.

Comment: but if I don't destroy them I leave handles floating around... So should I destroy them? Do you think the Process() objects that are returned are shared. I bet they are newly created for every request to Process.GetProcesses() and if you didn't Dispose you would probably have a handle leak...

Comment: Processes - no, you shouldn't (if you aren't creating them). Images or files or other stuff like that - yes, you should.

Comment: "I leave handles floating around" - they will be finalized so it's ok

Comment: I believe it is safe to call `Dispose` on a `Process` that you get from `GetProcesses()`.  It's documentation states that it `Creates an array of new Process components and associates them with existing process resources.`  These will not be used by other programs and disposing of them will not effect the processes they represent.